# How to show folders and don't show private files on the Google Drive Picker?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm new to the Google Picker, and I played a little bit with it. I'm working in a project were you can select a file, but I don't want to show private files in the picker, and to show folders instead of showing all the files without an order.

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Use the Google Loader script to load the google.picker script.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(createPicker);
        google.load('picker', '1', {'language':'es'});

        // Create and render a Picker object for searching images.
        function createPicker(){
            window.picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
                addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS).
                setCallback(function(data){
                    if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED){
                        var fileId = data.docs[0].id;
                        $.post('/poststatus.php', { q: fileId,  type: 'google' }, function(r){ $('#cuadro').html(r); });
                    }
                }).
                build();
        }
        function opengoogle(){ window.picker.setVisible(true); }
```

So when the user clicks on a button, the function opengoogle() is launched. I found a function (`DocsView.setIncludeFolders(boolean)`) that shows folders, but I don't know how to use it.

Thank you,
Adrià

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something more like:

```
var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
view.setIncludeFolders(true);
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().addView(view)
// ... build as normal
```